# Adding a button with a fixed position, over a CollectionView, in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

Adding elements to a CollectionView causes the page/view to expand, which in turn pushes the button to the bottom. How can I have it 'hover' in a fixed position on the page?

I've tried this (updated):

```
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CollectionView Grid.Row="0">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame
                         Margin="0">
                        <StackLayout
                                     Margin="0"
                                     Orientation="Vertical"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        </ScrollView>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Text="Add animal"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                Margin="0,0,20,22"
                VerticalOptions="End" />
    </Grid>
```

I think my main problem might be the placement of the button, to avoid it being pushed by other content.

Comment: don't use a ScrollView.  A CollectionView is inherently scrollable and should not be inside of another scroll container.  And define two rows for your Grid and place the Button in the 2nd row

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the code. Is that what you have in mind? I'll try to make a clean repro repo, to see if this works.

Comment: As one of the posted answers suggested, put both `<CollectionView>` and `<Button>` in the **SAME** `<Grid>` cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have it 'hover' in a fixed position on the page?

You can remove the `Grid.RowDefinitions` of the Grid and then place the Button in a fixed position via `HorizontalOptions="End"` and `VerticalOptions="End"`. In this scenario, the Button will be placed at the end and right side of the screen.

Here's the XAML code for your reference:

```
<Grid Margin="0">
        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame
                         Margin="0">
                        <VerticalStackLayout
                                     Margin="0"
                                 
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <HorizontalStackLayout
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
       
        <Button
                Text="Add animal"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                HorizontalOptions="End"
                Margin="0,0,10,10"
                VerticalOptions="End" />
</Grid>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hey there, I just got back. I tried out your solution, and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @eengstroem No worries, glad to see it works!